# Beam pipeline producing empty file

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have the following pipeline which produces an empty `foo.txt-00000-of-00001` when running in DirectRunner:

```py
def main():
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(TypeOptions).runtime_type_check = True

  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    messages = (p
      | MatchFiles("s3://foo_bar/*/*.gz", empty_match_treatment=EmptyMatchTreatment.DISALLOW)
      | beam.io.fileio.ReadMatches(compression=CompressionTypes.GZIP)
      | beam.io.WriteToText("gs://123/foo.txt")
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  main()
```

Looking into the console output it seems to find files in S3:

```
INFO:root:Finished listing 688 files in 0.534404993057251 seconds.
```

I would expect `ReadableFile`s not be able to be passed to `WriteToText` but there is no error in the output.
Setting `type_check_strictness` to `"ALL_REQUIRED"` does not help here either, because type hinting in the SDK itself is missing :(

Would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me about why there is no error and how to get and error or at least be able to trace the pipeline easily.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, the query in `MatchFiles` was wrong.
Seems like `MatchFiles` is ignoring `empty_match_treatment=EmptyMatchTreatment.DISALLOW` and not failing.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12304 . What version are you using?

Comment: I am using latest - 2.29